# How do I represent undefined numbers in C++ using large values?

Tags: c++, numbers, numerical-methods

In C++ I want to use a pair of large values to represent an undefined number:

```
void setUndefined(float& a) {
    a = set_undefined_value;
}

bool isUndefined(float a) {
    return a > is_undefined_value;
}
```

I want to use this approach for all numeric types, and from templatized code, so I was thinking along the lines of a template:

```
template<typename T>
    class Undefined {
    public:
        static T set_undefined_value() {
            NOT_IMPLEMENTED_FOR_THIS_TYPE_YET;
        }
        static T is_undefined_value() {
            NOT_IMPLEMENTED_FOR_THIS_TYPE_YET;
        }
    };

    // Template specialization for all numeric types: ...
```

**How do I find good pair of values for all numeric types?**

Is there e.g. some way I can use the std::numeric_limits::max() template?

If I write undefined values to file will they be portable across computers and OSes?

Comment: What's wrong with just using NaNs?

Comment: What's wrong with NaN? It even comes in two flavors.

Comment: Good question! Here is what I got when I suggested this some years ago: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.696908.19 The slow execution of floating point operations when it comes to NaN seems to be a problem. I also had some worries about reading from and writing to file being portable.

Comment: Just sticking with NaNs might still be faster than whatever hack you can come up with.

Comment: True, but I disagree that what I am suggesting above is a hack. Comparing against large values is something we have used at the two last companies I have been working for. Also my biggest problem with NaN is not performance but worries about portability. NaN is very convenient though since it automatically propagates undefined; any operation of a NaN is still a NaN.

Comment: NaN value is implementation-defined, so it's unlikely to be portable.

Comment: @Rost implementation-defined? I thought it was standard in [IEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)...

Comment: @Andy Do you really need highly optimized floating point math using NaNs? To me that sounds like a very unlikely edge case.

Comment: @Adriano C++ floating types could not conform to `IEEE 754/IEC 559`, it's not required by standard. See e.g. `numeric_limits::is_iec559`. Also `IEEE 754` defines the format of NaN, but not the exact value, so it can lead to problems if sticking to some single value.

Comment: Another big drawback of NaN (?): how do you distinguish between an error such as 0/0 and an undefined value?

Comment: Test for NaN before using the value, and test for 0 before dividing by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For floats and doubles pick a bit pattern for each that corresponds to NaN in IEEE754. Then you can make a macro for testing nan on all imaginable compilers and with all imaginable floating point optimizations.

For signed integers use the most negative value (0x80...)

For unsigned integers use the most positive value (0xFF...)

Comment: Thank you Minthos! How do I pick this bitpattern? Do I use numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN()? Also why use the most negative value instead of the most positive value for signed integers?

Comment: You can use quiet_NaN yes, just print its value as hexadecimal or view it in a debugger.

Use the most negative value because the range of negative values is 1 greater than the range of positive values (because 0 is in the positive range, even though it is neither positive or negative).

Comment: By "print its value" I mean of course "print its bit representation", i.e. place it in a union with an unsigned integer of the same size and print the integer as hex.